# How to get the name of a Document in Firebase Rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**How to know the name of a Document in security rules?**

I would like to know if it is possible to get the name of a Document in Firestore Database directly from the Security rules

**What i'm trying to achieve**

I would like to check if the User that get's data from a document has the same ID as the Document Name

**What I Tryed**

I tryed to use `resource.id` but i got a `Null value error.` in the rules test space

**My code and Dataset**

My code:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /databases/Leaderboard/{document}/{multiSegment=**} {
      allow read
      allow write: if request.auth.token.sub == resource.id
    
    }
  }
}
```

My Database

[image: My database]

Comment: What do you mean by "Document Name"?

Comment: Every Document in a collection has a name. This is what I’m talking about.

Comment: Can show us a screenshot?

Comment: I cannot see any name inside the document, only a `catSeen` property.

Comment: My bad, it's changed, now @AlexMamo

Comment: There is another field called `userID`, but no `name` field at all.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

Here is my code :

```
    rules_version = '2';

    service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /databases/Leaderboard/{userEMail}/{multiSegment=**} {
      //allow read
      allow write: if request.auth.token.sub == "AWS" && request.auth != null
      allow read: if request.auth != null && request.auth.token.email == userEMail
    }
  }
}
```